# Firefox reader mode begins noise from speakers

Tags: linux, firefox, audio

I'm on MATE Linux based on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS; Firefox 66.0.3.  When I click a "Toggle reader view" to enable the reader mode, white noise begins playing from the speakers.  It goes away when I close the browser.

What could be the reason, how can I investigate what happens and how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's reader view has a built-in text-to-speech feature. This feature depends on the OS to function, as the TTS voices are not built into Firefox itself. You're probably experiencing some incompatibility with MATE Linux's sound drivers or TTS software (or lack thereof). Do you see the TTS button in reader view? If so, see if you can change the voice.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042146) details how a user configured their TTS to work with the 'Festival' voice on Ubuntu.

[image: Reader view TTS]